# if statement syntax. Wrong output

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
x=11

for n in range(1,x+1):
    #print(n)
    if (x%n)==0:
        if n == 1 and n==x:
            print(f"{x} is a prime number")
            break       
        else:
            #print(n)
            print(f"{x} is not a prime number")
            break
```

the output is: 11 is not a prime number.
According to my knowledge the logic is correct but why this wrong output.

Comment: `n == 1 and n==x` this condition will never return true. Because if n is 1 it can't be equal to `x` which is 11.

Comment: This would seem to be the problem: `n == 1 and n==x`.  This can only be true when `x == 1`

Comment: Change "and" to "or" to fix.  (also, this is an ineffecient way to test for primality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are trying to implement for deciding in `x` is prime appears to be the following:

*Given an integer number `x` as input, loop over all the integer numbers, `n`, between `1` and `x`.
If we find an `n` which divides `x` exactly, and if that `n` is not `1` or `x`, then output that `x` is not a prime number. Otherwise output that `x` is a prime number.*

Given this description, you can see where your Python goes wrong. In the described algorithm, we can't tell if `x` is prime until we have tried all the `n`, and decided that they don't divide `x`, unless `n == 1` or `n == x`. But in your example code, your test for primality (which incidentally is wrong) comes before we finish looping over all the `n`.

Instead, the algorithm says we should try all the `n` first, checking if `x` is not prime, and if we can't find one which shows `x` is *not* prime, then `x`  obviously *is* prime. So that's what we'll do in Python...

From the description, we can write a test of whether a number is *not* a prime number:

```
x % n == 0 and n != 1 and n != x
```

If any `n` gives `True` for this condition, then `x` is not prime. We can do that for every `n`, and stop looping when we've found one:

```
for n in range(1,x+1):
    if x % n == 0 and n != 1 and n != x:
        print(f"{x} is not a prime number")
        break
```

Now, if we get to the end of the loop without `break`ing, then we know `x` is prime. How do we know when we finished the loop? One option is to use a flag variable, instead of printing the output straight away. E.g.

```
isprime = True
for n in range(1,x+1):
    if x % n == 0 and n != 1 and n != x:
        isprime = False
        break

if isprime:
    print(f"{x} is a prime number")
else:
    print(f"{x} is not a prime number")
```

This will work for you. Its not the most efficient algorithm for primality testing, but it is simple and it works.

NOTE:
As a quick first step, you don't need the `n == 1` and `n == x` tests if you just loop from `n=2` to `n=x-1`. E.g.

```
isprime = True
for n in range(2, x):
    if x % n == 0:
        isprime = False
        break
```

Comment: @aneroid I actually like it that way! But if you find it odd, other likely will too, so edited